# Is there a way to observe that an DOM elements css('font-size') has changed?

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I want to display a warning to the user if they have Safari's "Never use font sizes smaller than..." preference set. I create a div with `font-size: 1px` off the screen, and read its font-size with `$.css('font-size')` in a property.

This works fine for loading a page. However, I would like to make it live, so that the warning appears/disappears when the user checks/unchecks the preference. I've verified that the element itself is live -- if I check/uncheck the preference than use the console to check the font-size it changes.

Is there any way to observe this change from ember?

Comment: You can use a timeout... nothing wrong with that. There's also MutationObserver (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), your mileage may vary. Not cross-browser, but the setting you're trying to look at is browser-specific anyway.

Comment: Latest Safari does support MutationObservers, fyi: http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about MutationObserver, it will come in handy. However, I tested it and it does not fire when changing the preference. Which makes sense, because only the `computedStyle` changes, which is what `$.css('css-attr')` accesses. If you look at `$.attr('style')`, it doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the Dom objects thoroughly & testing MutationObserver and other more esoteric possibilities, I regretfully came to the conclusion that polling is the only way to observe observe a change to this setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function myFunction(){
    setInterval(function(){
        //Verify font size and show message
    }, intervalInMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would use the Ember scheduler. But I was hoping not to add more background polling to the app if there is already a built in way.